# Sending an "identify" request to "threads.io" using php

Tags: php, web, analytics

What I want to do is to send an "identify" request to "threads.io" using php, however, I didn't find a way to do it (I couldn't even find a "threads.io" documentation for php). Does anyone know the proper way to do it? (syntax, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use curl.  Here's a basic script that will do it.

```
// You must use UTC timezone
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$project_key = 'your project key';

$data = array(
    'userId' => '12',
    'traits' => array(
            'name' => 'Jeff',
            'email' => 'jeff@example.com',
        ),
        'timestamp' => date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s') . '.000Z',
);

$data = json_encode($data);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://input.threads.io/v1/identify");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$project_key:''");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

A good starting place to understanding curl is: http://www.hackingwithphp.com/15/10/2/your-first-curl-scripts

And of course php.net: http://php.net/curl